# Как мне запустить скрипт из файла на JS или html?

Tags: javascript, html, python

У меня есть сайт на django. Есть код html и отдельный файл message.py
Не подскажите как можно запустить message.py из html? Если из html нельзя, то как это сделать на JS?
Вот пример задумки html:

```
<form action="">
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email..." name="sender_mail">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text_message" placeholder="Your text here..."></textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="message.py" value="Send message">
</div>
```

Вот message.py:

```
import smtplib
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if form.getvalue("text_message"):
    mes = form.getvalue("text_message")

if form.getvalue("sender_mail"):
    sent = form.getvalue("sender_mail")
message = mes+" "+sent 
mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.ru", 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('sender@mail.ru', 'senderspassword')
mail.sendmail('sender@mail.ru', 'tech_support@mail.ru', message)
mail.close()
```

Comment: onClick="this.form.action = 'message.py';this.form.target='_self'" не подходит?

Comment: Я вам уже отвечал на этот вопрос и давал ссылки на справку Django. http://archive.fo/WQzKt То, что вы почему-то повторяете вопрос, ответов не изменит. Если вам что-то непонятно в ответах, лучше так и спросите, что именно непонятно

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что это справка по Django, даже если я напишу код на нём, то как его ипользовать в самом html&

Comment: @Pashok Если бы вы не поленились прочитать справку Django, то увидели бы, что там всё написано и про HTML тоже :) [Sending email, Quick example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/) / [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) / [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/)

Comment: А вообще всё выглядит так, будто вы даже [обучение для новичков в Django](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/) не проходили. Без этого пытаться ответить на ваш вопрос немножко бессмысленно

Comment: Этот проект мне уже завтра сдавать. Нам сказали его делать без каких-либо вводных материалов. Просто как-нибудь сделать. Разумеется я просто не успеваю всё прочитать (

Comment: Когда сказали его делать? Теперь всё выглядит так, будто вы много месяцев ленились что-либо делать и пытаетесь тяп-ляп и в продакшен в последние дни перед дедлайном, а это ещё меньше мотивирует вам помогать :)

Comment: Не. Я только студент. У меня помимо этого ещё и экзамены, к которым тоже готовиться надо

Comment: Раз вы студент, уверен, что времени прочитать обучение для новичков у вас было много. Теперь мне остаётся вам только посочувствовать)

Comment: Спасибо хоть на этом. Во всяком случае лучше учителя объяснили, у которого основная специальность не программирование.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос, который, как мне кажется, подходит для моего недолгого обращения с html и python:

```
<form metod="post" action="message.py">
<input type="submit" onclick="alert=("Отправлено");"></input>
</form>
```

Теперь осталось принять введённые значения и отправить.
На мой взгляд этот способ решения немного лучше, чем писать всё в jango файле. Да самого кода больше, но он разбит на файлы, с которыми как-то проще работать. Если всё писать в jango, то код будет сливаться и станет плохим для понимания.